# R. I have a vector with values. I would like to implement a formula that uses CDF and PDF

Tags: r, cdf

Suppose that I have a vector with values, for example:

```
MyVector=(99,100,100,98,99,101,99,101,102,100)
```

From here I would like to use a formula that would give me CDF(x)/PDF(x) for those values of x that are defined. I can use the function ecdf to get the numerator:

```
MyCDF <- ecdf(MyVector)
```

Then I would be able to write, say, MyCDF(100) which would give me 0.7 as the result.

But it looks like there is no similar function for PDF (the denominator)?

As a result I would like to be able to get the following table in the example above:

| Value | PDF | CDF | CDFdivPDF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 98 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 1 |
| 99 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 1.33 |
| 100 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 2.33 |
| 101 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 4.5 |
| 102 | 0.1 | 1 | 10 |

Also, I would like to make a plot where values are on the x-axis, and PDF, CDF, CDFdivPDF are plotted.

Could you please help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what are your coding problems?

Comment: Stack Overflow works best when you only ask a single, specific programming question. Could you edit your question to include where exactly you are running into a problem? Respectfully, as it read right now, broadly stating that you need *some* function and also that you want to make some unspecified plot comes off as *can someone do my work for me?* This may not be your intention, but you will likely get much better, faster help by editing your question to include a targeted, specific coding-related question. Good luck!

Comment: For a discrete variable like this, your pdf is just proportions. I.e.`table(MyVector)/length(MyVector)`.

Comment: @jpsmith and Peter: Thank you for the comments. I am sorry that my question may look like "someone do my work". I have tried to use hist function and ggplot (geom_histogram and stat_ecdf) which would only plot, but not give me a number that I could use in a formula. I tried to use "table" which would give me numbers on the screen, but I did not know how to get one specific number. I wrote it in the question: "But it looks like there is no similar function for PDF (the denominator)?". That would solve my problem. I did not write what I have tried, but will do next time I ask a question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ecdf` like below

```
x <- sort(unique(MyVector))
cdf <- ecdf(MyVector)(x)
pdf <- diff(c(0, cdf))

data.frame(
    value = x,
    CDF = cdf,
    PDF = pdf,
    CDFdivPDF = cdf / pdf
)
```

such that

```
  value CDF PDF CDFdivPDF
1    98 0.1 0.1  1.000000
2    99 0.4 0.3  1.333333
3   100 0.7 0.3  2.333333
4   101 0.9 0.2  4.500000
5   102 1.0 0.1 10.000000
```